# Extend rolle's theorem to complex functions?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, roots

If $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree n with n distinct real roots $r _1$<,..., <$r_n$, then there exists exactly one root of $f '(z)$ in between any consecutive root of $f(z)$.

The context of this homework problem is the Gauss-Lucas theorem, and so I tried to play with it. I.e. I tried to use induction: suppose the statement is true for polynomial $g(z)$ of degree n-1, then I want to show that for $f(z)=g(z)(z-r_n)$, the root of $f'(z)$ cannot be less than $r_{n-1}$,combining the theorem that for $f'(z_0)=0$, $z_0$ is bounded within the convex hull, i.e. $r_1<z_0<r_n$,then we get $r_{n-1}<z_0<r_n$, completing the proof.

I did not get anywhere by this approach in the past few hours, so I am just thinking, is it OK to just simply say that since $f(z)=(z-r_1)...(z-r_n)$, it can be viewed as a real-valued function, and then apply rolle's theorem to complete the proof?

Then what would be the rigorous way of saying "it can be viewed as a real-valued function"?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general that $f(z)=(z-r_1)\cdots (z-r_n)$. What is true is $$ f(z)=c_n(z-r_1)\cdots (z-r_n)$$ where $c_n$ is the leading coefficients. Since multiplication by a nonzero scalar does not change the zeros (including those of the derivative), it is indeed a good idea to consider $c_n^{-1}f_n$, which is real-valued on the real axis. The precise meaning of the latter: the restriction to $\mathbb R$ takes values in $\mathbb R$. The usual Rolle's theorem applies to such a function.